# What does Hashirama mean by the effects of the chakra rods?

Tags: naruto

In Chapter 661, Hashirama said "These rods are forced through our chakra points, which means that the chances of us moulding chakra are probably nil". He said it in the context of "even if the rods are removed". Since those under Edo Tensei can recover on their own after some time, what did he mean by this?

Comment: Awesome obeservation!!!!!! if they were under Edo Tensai,he shouldn't had said that......... since ppl under ET recover on it's own,why did Hashirama exclaimed like that? I think Kishimoto went a bit out of track....... i am waiting for someone to answer this question!!!!!! good observation though!!!!

Answer (score 2):

While people do regenerate under Edo Tensei, the process of regeneration can be slow and tedious. Madara has reached new heights and can attack at any given moment. Hashirama knows his chakra circulation is obstructed and it could take a while for him to heal fully. Thus, he is giving Sasuke this precaution along with a jutsu.

Refer to Minato's statement below. Also recall how Minato lost his arm and still hasn't regenerated yet. Hashirama knows that if Madara acts quickly, he won't be able to stop Madara.
[image]

Comment: I have a doubt:- why is there a so much difference in their regeneration process?Isn't Oruchimaru's ET not efficient enough?Kabuto's ET where able to regenerate quickly compared to the one by Oruchimaru........

Comment: Kabuto also has the advantage being alive and experimenting while Orochimaru wasn't. Also consider the fact that Kabuto used Zetsu clones, to which he can research and practice on. Orochimaru did not have opportunity. Needless to say, Kabuto's ET did not regenerate instantly. Madara is the only exception because he is simply on another level. He also stole sage mode and mastered it within mere seconds.

Comment: Forgot about the zetsu's clone with which Kabuto resurrected the dead ones...... thanks for the info.... +1 again to u

Comment: what jutsu did hashirama give sasuke?